# Java 8 Offset Date Parsing

Tags: java, java-8, timezone-offset, java-time

I need to parse a String in the following format `2015-01-15-05:00` to LocalDate(or smth else) in UTC.
The problem is that the following code:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2015-01-15-05:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE));
```

outputs `2015-01-15` ignoring the offset. The desired output is `2015-01-16`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that the result must be 2015-01-16? Obviously you make an untold assumption about what the non-existing clock time shall be like (always the same for all of your input strings???). For me, the date is just as parsed: 2015-01-15. There is no connection to UTC because of missing time part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest answer is to use `OffsetDateTime` to represent the data, but you need to default the time:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-01-15-05:00", fmt);
LocalDate date = dt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
```

`ZonedDateTime` is useful if dealing with time-zones, but when you are only dealing with offsets, `OffsetDateTime` is simpler.

In general, application code should not hold variables of type `TemporalAccessor`. If you see that, there is generally a better way.

Comment: Direct and authoritative. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @JodaStephen, it still outputs 2015-01-15

Comment: @JodaStephen, it should be .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24)

Comment: You obviously need the end of day, so 24 makes sense. I'll leave the example as 0 as probably most users would choose start of day.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I've found a solution. Here it is:

```
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse("2015-01-15-05:00");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.from(temporalAccessor), LocalTime.MAX, ZoneId.from(temporalAccessor));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate());
```