# How to convert String to Date with TimeZone?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timezone

I'm trying to convert my `String` in `Date` + Timezone. 
I get my String from a `DateTime` Variable (here: xyz).
My code:

```
String abc = xyz.toString("yyyy-MM-ddZZ");
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddXXX");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(abc);
System.out.println("Date: " + sdf.format(date));
```

Error:

> Invalid format: "2017-01-03+01:00" is malformed at "+01:00"

If I try `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` it works but without the Timezone ("+01:00")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: The timezone had to be placed after a time, which is a thing you don't have in your String

Comment: @DamCx If I print out my String, I have the Timezone in it. It's from a Datetime Format.

Comment: Yes, with time, but in the format you want to parse (`yyyy-MM-ddXXX`), you don't have the Time and `SimpleDateFormat` will take it for a `Date`

Comment: Any reason why you are still trying to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class and its equally outdated friend `Date`? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: A `Date` cannot contain a time-zone, but you can have the offset from UTC information separately.

Comment: @OleV.V. How can I do it? It's so new for me.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you!

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796443/5207900 to a question similar to yours.

Comment: A date-only with an offset-from-UTC makes no sense by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The input has a date - year, month, day - and an offset - the [difference from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) - but to build a `java.util.Date`, you also need the time: hour, minutes, seconds, fraction of seconds.

`SimpleDateFormat` is terrible because it does some "magic", setting the missing fields to default values. Another problem is that the `X` pattern doesn't work for all Java versions, and the documentation sucks.

You can use the new Java 8 classes, as explained. With them, you can parse the input, choose the default values to be used for the time fields and convert to `java.util.Date`, if that's what you need:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE)
    // set hour to midnight
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0).toFormatter();

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-01-03+01:00", fmt); // 2017-01-03T00:00+01:00
```

The `OffsetDateTime` will have the time set to midnight, but you can change it to whatever values you need, while with `SimpleDateFormat` it's not possible, because it uses internal default values and you can't control it.

And the date and offset were correctly set to the values in the input string. You can then convert to `java.util.Date` if you want:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

You can also get the individual "pieces" of the date if you want:

```
// get just the date
LocalDate localDate = odt.toLocalDate(); // 2017-01-03
// get just the offset
ZoneOffset offset = odt.getOffset(); // +01:00
```

**PS:** the offset `+01:00` is **not** the same thing as a timezone. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Very elegant solution to get close to a “date with time zone”, as the title asked for. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String abc = "2017-01-03+01:00";
    TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse(abc);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(parsed);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(parsed);
    System.out.println("Date: " + date + "; offset: " + offset + '.');
```

This prints:

```
Date: 2017-01-03; offset: +01:00.
```

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and recommend you do the same. The `Date` class is long outdated (sorry, no pun intended) and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Don’t use them. The modern API is so much nicer to work with. Only if you need a `java.util.Date` and/or a `java.util.TimeZone` for a legacy API that you cannot change, convert like this:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(offset).toInstant());
    TimeZone oldfashionedTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(offset);
    System.out.println("Old-fashioned date: " + oldfashionedDate
            + "; old-fashioned time-zone: " + oldfashionedTimeZone.getDisplayName() + '.');
```

On my computer this prints:

```
Old-fashioned date: Tue Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2017; old-fashioned time-zone: GMT+01:00.
```

I happen to be in a time zone that agrees with your offset from UTC, so it’s fairly obvious that the conversion has given the correct result. In other time zones the output will be more confusing because `Date.toString()` uses the JVM’s time zone setting for generating the string, but the `Date` will still be correct.

**A date *with* a time zone?** Neither a `LocalDate` nor a `Date` can hold a time zone in them, so you need to have the offset information separately. Interestingly your string seems to follow a “ISO-8601-like” format for an offset date that is even represented by a built-in formatter that has ISO in its name. If Java had contained an `OffsetDate` or a `ZonedDate` class, I would have expected such a class to parse your string into just one object and even without an explicit formatter. Unfortunately no such class exists, not even in the ThreeTen-Extra project, as far as I can tell at a glance.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), more classes developed along with `java.time`.
- **EDIT:** [See my updated code run live on ideone](https://www.ideone.com/RFa0DR).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I get an error at LocalDate-line: Instance method 'from' cannot be invoked in static context. Can you help me?

Comment: Klingt merkwürdig, @Alexa666. `LocalDate.from` is a static method (not an instance method; see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-)). Which `LocalDate` class have you imported? (Look for something like `import xxxx.xxxx.LocalDate;` near the top of your Java file.) It should be `java.time.LocalDate` (or if using the ThreeTen Backport on Java 6 or 7, `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`).

Comment: Hmm actually it is `import java.time.LocalDate;`

Comment: I wish I could help, @Alexa666. At the bottom of my answer I have added a link to where you can see my code run. Maybe you can compare, or copy my entire program and see whether you can make it run on your computer. If all else fails, you may post a new question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The class `OffsetDate` had once existed in jsr310-project but was finally thrown out by Oracle because it was considered as not so useful (its main purpose is just to build a bridge to xml-schema type xsd:date with offset).

Comment: About your claim that an offset date is ISO-8601, I think it is not (have not found any mention in the original paper of ISO which instead speaks about offsets only in context of local time components).

Comment: Thanks, @Meno, for you (as always) knowledgeable comments. I have edited. To me, conceptually an “offset date” and a “zoned date” still make perfect sense, and this SO question is not the first about an “offset date”; see for example [Java 8 Offset Date Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810324/java-8-offset-date-parsing).

Comment: Just discovered that the formatter is built in. My code became one line shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> "2017-01-03+01:00"

I thought it a similar ISO 8601 format date string, but actually not [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Thanks  @Meno Hochschild and @Basil Bourque's indication.

It is so luck that this method works for such format's string: `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime`, it will return a `Calendar`:

```
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.parseDate("2017-01-03+01:00").getTime());
```

Output:

> Tue Jan 03 07:00:00 CST 2017

From the method javadoc:

> public static Calendar parseDate(String lexicalXSDDate)
>   Converts the string argument into a Calendar value.
>   
>   Parameters: lexicalXSDDate - A string containing lexical
>   representation of xsd:Date.
>    Returns: A Calendar value represented by
>   the string argument.
>    Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if string
>   parameter does not conform to lexical value space defined in XML
>   Schema Part 2: Datatypes for xsd:Date.

Comment: It is not ISO-8601 (see the original paper - offsets require a time, too) but derived from XML-schema where it is an extra feature and was seemingly introduced for obscure symmetry reasons.

Comment: No, that String is *not* ISO 8601 compliant, as noted by Meno Hochschild. The ISO 8601 formats are sensible and practical, whereas that string is neither. Please correct your Answer, or provide documentation to back your claim.

Comment: The solution looks elegant, and though the `Calendar` class returned by `parseDate` is capable of holding both the date and the “time zone” (which in this example isn’t a true time zone), `Calendar` is also poorly designed and long outdated. And its `getTime` method throws away the time zone information (as your example output shows).