# SOAP Web Service parsing Date from String returning d-1 value

Tags: xml, date, timezone, cxf, java-6

I'm using `org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate(StringDate)` to parse the input string date from XML to JAVA date. But i got a Date objects with day-1 value.

For example

```
<birth>1939-11-19+01:00</birth>
```

I want to ignore the offset. I want only the date, so no matter what the offset is, I should get

```
Sun Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1939
```

But I do get:

```
Sat Nov 18 23:00:00 CET 1939
```

The issue is at the level of date's time offset. I tried to fix it with ignoring the time offset but that didn't work. I'm using java 6 (constraint project). Any ideas?

My best attempt at a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
public static Date parse(final String str) {
    Calendar c = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(str);
    System.out.println(str + "\t" + c.getTime().getTime() / 1000);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Date with TimeZone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418975/how-to-convert-string-to-date-with-timezone)

Comment: If you only want the date, compared to the linked question you can do it a bit simpler: `LocalDate.parse("1939-11-19+01:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE)`.

Comment: I have a constraint to use java 6

Comment: Poor you. :-) Can you add [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project? Then it will work in Java 6 too.

Comment: There are some known issues. The Hijrah calendar system does not work. Formatting and parsing often depends on data only available in Java SE 8. Zone id and text parsing is significantly less powerful.

Comment: Moreover, i'm using Ant for dependency management

Comment: You may still use the backport for this isolated problem (I can’t believe Ant can‘t handle it). Alternatively `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` (built into Java 6) can parse your date string into a `GregorianCalendar` (this is also what CXF is using behind the scenes). This might be a way through too.

Comment: Funny, when on my Java 8 I emulate what the CXF method does (according to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils/cxf-xjc-runtime/2.6.0/org/apache/cxf/xjc/runtime/DataTypeAdapter.java#DataTypeAdapter.parseDate%28java.lang.String%29)), I get `Sun Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1939`.

Comment: Since I could not reproduce, you should probably give us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, what would be your desired outcome if the offset from XML was `-01:00`? If it was `+03:00`? Would you want `Sun Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1939` in both cases, or would you want the time to be different?

Comment: I want to ignore completely the offset, i want only the date Sun Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1939 in both cases.

Comment: public static Date parse(final String str) {
        Calendar c = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(str);
        System.out.println(str + "\t" + (c.getTime().getTime()/1000));
        return c.getTime();
    }

Comment: I have reproduced your observed behaviour after setting my JVM’s default time zone to Europe/Monaco. Europe/Monaco and my usual time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, both print as `CET`, but Monaco was at offset 0 from UTC on that date in 1939, while Copenhagen was at +01, hence the different behaviour.

Comment: Have you an idea about how to install threeTen backport using Ant ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164735/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-hoss).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    String birth = "1939-11-19+01:00";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(birth, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
    System.out.println(date);
```

This prints

```
1939-11-19
```

A `java.time.LocalDate` is a date without time-of-day, so this matches your requirements exactly. At the same time `java.util.Date` and friends are long outdated and have proven poorly designed. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with. So my first recommendation is you stop here.

If you do need a `Date`, for example for a legacy API, first realize that despite the name it does not represent a date. It represents a point in time, and at that point in time the date will not be the same everywhere. This probably caused your problem, as you are aware: `parseDate` and `parseDateTime` parse your string into 00:00 at the specified offset from UTC on the date in question. At this point in time, the date may not be the same in your time zone, so when you print the `Date` you get, thereby invoking its `toString` method, you may get a different date. I understand that you want the time at 0:00 in your own time zone instead (CET, probably Central European Time, in turn a name of several different time zones that may be at offsets 0 or +01 on that date in 1939; the result you observed would make sense in time zones Europe/Paris, Africa/Ceuta, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Madrid and Europe/Monaco, all of which were at offset 0). To convert:

```
    Date oldfashionedDateObject 
            = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDateObject);
```

This printed

```
Sun Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1939
```

I tested with my time zone set to America/New_York and to Europe/Moscow, and always got `Sun Nov 19 00:00:00`, only in different time zones, `EST` and `MSK`.

### Java 6 and ThreeTen Backport

I understand that you have to use Java 6. `java.time` has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in the ThreeTen Backport. So get this from the link at the bottom and add it to your project, and the above code will work except the conversion happens a little differently:

```
    Date oldfashionedDateObject
            = DateTimeUtils.toDate(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

You don’t need to rewrite all of your code to use the ThreeTen Backport, and especially not if there are parts where you don’t trust the modern API to behave the way you want. The above snippet can coexist nicely with the code you already have.

### The really really old-fashioned way

If you really insist, the way I could find to get the `Date` you want using `DatatypeConverter` and `Calendar`:

```
    Calendar calWithParsedOffset = DatatypeConverter.parseDate(birth);
    Calendar calWithMyTimeZone = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    calWithMyTimeZone.clear();
    calWithMyTimeZone.set(calWithParsedOffset.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calWithParsedOffset.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calWithParsedOffset.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = calWithMyTimeZone.getTime();
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDateObject);
```

We can’t just change the offset or time zone of the `Calendar` we got from parsing since this will not change its point in time and therefore not the `Date` object we get. Instead we need to set a different `Calendar` object to the year, month and day-of-month of the first `Calendar`. The call to `clear()` sets hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0. This snippet too has been tested with my JVM’s time zone set to America/New_York and to Europe/Moscow.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.